# Java DateTime convert

Tags: java, datetime

I'm converting a specific datetime fromat by deducting -5 minutes from the current date I retrieve:

csvFileDate is a list of dates with format, `yyyyMMddhhmm`.  Below is the code I'm using but its converting the date wrong:

```
private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmm");
private List<String> csvFileDates = new ArrayList<String>();

....


Collections.sort(csvFileDates);
String currDate = csvFileDates.get(csvFileDates.size() -1);
System.out.println("DATE1 " + currDate);
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(dateFormat.parse(currDate));
c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -5);
System.out.println("DATE2 " + c.getTime());
```

output:

```
DATE1 201505181208
DATE2 Mon May 18 00:03:00 SGT 2015
```

Another:

```
DATE1 201505181213
DATE2 Mon May 18 00:08:00 SGT 2015
```

Any idea why?

Comment: What is wrong about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have 24 hours time format. So you have to use uppercase H for hours:

> H Hour in day (0-23)
>   h Hour in am/pm (1-12)

```
private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm");
```

See the documantation of [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more details.

Comment: Thank you, didn't notice it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `HH` instead of `hh` for hour of the day, as stated [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)